# Amazon Cloudfront removes Referer header

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, referer

I am using Amazon CloudFront to deliver some HDS files. I have an origin server which check the HTTP HEADER REFERER and in case is no allowed it block it.

The problem is that cloud front is removing the referer header, so it is not forwarded to the origin.

Is it possible to tell Amazon not to do it?

Comment: CloudFront is a cache, so it doesn't cache varying parts of the request on purpose. If it did then every requestor after the first hit would appear to come from the same origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In today's newsletter amazon announced that it is now possible to forward request headers with cloudfront. See: http://aws.amazon.com/de/about-aws/whats-new/2014/06/26/amazon-cloudfront-device-detection-geo-targeting-host-header-cors/

Answer (score 13):

Within days of writing the answer below, changes have been announced to Cloudfront.  Cloudfront will now pass through headers you select and can add some headers of its own.

However, much of what I stated below remains true.  Note that in the announcement, an option is offered to forward all headers which, as I suggested, would effectively disable caching.  There's also an option to forward specific headers, which will cause Cloudfront to cache the object against the complete set of forwarded headers -- not just the uri -- meaning that the effectiveness of the cache is somewhat reduced, since Cloudfront has no option but to assume that the inclusion of the header might modify the response the server will generate for that request.

> Each of your CloudFront distributions now contains a list of headers that are to be forwarded to the origin server. You have three options:
>
> `None` - This option requests the original behavior.
>
> `All` - This option forwards all headers and effectively disables all caching at the edge.
>
> `Whitelist` - This option give you full control of the headers that are to be forwarded. The list starts out empty, and grows as you add more headers. You can add common HTTP headers by choosing them from a list. You can also add "custom" headers by simply entering the name.
>
> If you choose the `Whitelist` option, each header that you add to the list becomes part of the cache key for the URLs associated with the distribution. Adding a header to the list simply tells CloudFront that the value of the header can affect the content returned by the origin server.
>
> http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enhanced-cloudfront-customization/

---

Cloudfront does remove the `Referer` header along with several others that are not particularly meaningful -- or whose presence would cause illogical consequences --  in the world of cached content.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html

Just like cookies, if the `Referer:` header were allowed to remain, such that the origin could see it and react to it, that would imply that the object should be cached based on the request plus the referring page, which would seem to largely defeat the cachability of objects.  Otherwise, if the origin did react to an undesired referer and send no-cache responses, that would be all well and good until the first legitimate request came in, the response to which would be served to subsequent requesters regardless of their referer, also largely defeating the purpose.

RFC-2616 Section 13 requires that a cache return a response that has been "checked for equivalence with what the origin server would have returned," and this implies that the response be valid based on *all* headers in the request.

The same thing goes for `User-agent` and other headers an origin server might use to modify its response... if you need to react to these values at the origin, there's little obvious purpose for serving them with a CDN.

Referring page-based tests are quite a primitive measure, the way many people use them, since headers are so trivial to forge.

If you are dealing with a platform that you don't control, and this is something you need to override (with a dummy value, just to keep the existing system "happy,") then a reverse proxy in front of the origin server could serve such a purpose, with Cloudfront using the reverse proxy as its origin.

Comment: So you say that cloud front is not a CDN but a static-only  delivery network and it is imposible to set a "no-store" rule?

Comment: I said neither.  Cloudfront is a CDN that is based on a fetch-through-and-cache-at-the-edge model.  As such, there's little point in using it to deliver content that isn't the same for every requester, since you are then defeating the cache and offloading nothing from your origin.  If you are trying to secure your content, Cloudfront has a mechanism for this, that doesn't defeat the cache: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/de/about-aws/whats-new/2014/06/26/amazon-cloudfront-device-detection-geo-targeting-host-header-cors/

Comment: I have one question here, why does cloudfront cache based on the headers it passes to the origin? I have an Authorization header which I want to pass through whose value change quite frequently and if cloudfront caches based on it then this will nullify the use of a cache.

Comment: @RamPatra in the case of the `Authorization` header, how would CloudFront know a request was authorized?   As I noted above, *"Cloudfront has no option but to assume that the inclusion of the header might modify the response the server will generate for that request."*  For resources that don't require authorization, create an additional cache behavior and path pattern (without forwarding `Authorization`) so that they can be effectively cached.  Or, for secured content to be served from the cache, you need CloudFront signed URLs or signed cookies.